# Issue with vectorization in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have an application where I need to merge two solutions obtained from the `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` in python. The actual application is a bit more complicated, but the following example shows the idea:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp import numpy as np

def lotkavolterra(t, z, a, b, c, d):

    x, y = z

    return [a*x - b*x*y, -c*y + d*x*y]


sol_1 = solve_ivp(lotkavolterra, [0, 10], [10, 5], args=(1.5, 1, 3, 1), dense_output=True).sol  
sol_2 = solve_ivp(lotkavolterra, [10, 15], [10, 5], args=(1.5, 1, 3, 1), dense_output=True).sol

def sol_comb(t):

    if t <= 10:
        return sol_1(t)
    else:
        return sol_2(t)
```

I want to be able to use the merged or combined solution `sol_comb` on numpy arrays. Hence I tried to define a vectorized solution as follows:

```
sol_comb_vect = np.vectorize(sol_comb)
```

The following code, where I only call the functions on scalars, works fine:

```
print("sol_1 for t = 2",sol_1(2)) 
print("sol_2 for t = 11",sol_2(11))
print("sol_comb for t = 11",sol_comb(11))
print("sol_comb_vect for t = 11",sol_comb_vect(11))
```

The individual solutions `sol_1` and `sol_2` are apparently vectorized, since the following works fine:

```
print("sol_1 for t = [2,3]",sol_1(np.array([2])))
print("sol_2 for t = [11,13]",sol_2(np.array([11,13])))
```

However, if I call the non-vectorized function `sol_comb` on an array, as in the following example, I get the expected `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`:

```
print("sol_comb for t = [11,13]",sol_comb(np.array([11,13])))
```

I was expecting the vectorized version `sol_comb_vect` to work. However, in the following, I get the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

```
print("sol_comb_vect for t = [11,13]",sol_comb_vect(np.array([11,13])))
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I would also be happy to merge the two `OdeSolution` instances in a cleaner way. In principle I think this should be possible, by using the time values and interpolants for `sol_1` and `sol_2`, respectively.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks, it should be fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify the signature for your output when you vectorize your function since **by default the *pyfunc* you pass to np.vectorize() is assumed to take scalars as input and output** [see doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). And I assume that your **ValueError** is caused by that. So try this:

```
sol_comb_vect = np.vectorize(sol_comb, signature='()->(n)')
sol_comb_vect(np.array([2, 11, 13]))
```

output:

```
array([[0.60031288, 0.09618044],
       [0.21298705, 1.36999868],
       [2.58274789, 0.01857732]])
```

I don't know if this is the expected output tho. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Note that I can't upvote it due to my low rep.

Indeed, this works well for the example above. However, I realized that in the actual application, it doesn't quite work. The reason is that I need to be able to give t both as an array of shape (1,) and of shape (1,1). In the latter case, the output dimension should still be (2,) rather than (1,2) as one gets with the fix you suggested.

Do you know if there is an (elegant/pythonic) way to handle this?

Comment: If your inputs comes only in shapes of `(1,)` and `(1,1)` you can add `reshape(2,)` at the end like so: `sol_comb_vect(np.array([[13]])).reshape(2,)`. This should work for both cases I believe.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That seems to work, at least for the cases considered so far.